# How can I prevent MUI Select component width from getting expanded as I select multiple options?

Tags: css, material-ui, css-grid

**Please take a look at the small demo I built on codesandbox here**

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-butterfly-tdo116?file=/demo.tsx:1446-2428)

I am using MUI Select component with multiple props to be able to select multiple options. I don't want to use fixed with. I am using grid to split the width equally for all the children. I have given all the children 1fr like so.

```
<Grid container>
        <Grid xs item>
          Filter By Site
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs item>
          Filter By Group
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs item>
          Filter By Cams
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">Name</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
              id="demo-multiple-name"
              multiple
              value={personName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
              MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
              {names.map((name) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={name}
                  value={name}
                  style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
                >
                  {name}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

The thing is the Input element keeps getting expanded as I select multiple options. How can I make sure it remains the same width equal as the other siblings?

Answer (score 1):

You migth use fullWidth prop inside a TextField component and set it to be false instead of Select component.

Something like this, for example:

```
<TextField
  id="age"
  className="text-field-short"
  ref="textfield"
  hintText="Full name"
  errorText={this.state.errorTextName}
  onChange={this._handleErrorInputChange}
  fullWidth={false} // set fullWidth prop to false to prevent expansion
/>
```